Remove lines from a table
For this my code how can I remove the lines that I highlighted in the attach photo?
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Different types of datasets with data type Int32.}
\label{tabadf}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Dataset}  &  test   & P\_value  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Critical} & ss? & Comp. \\
\hline
& & & & 1\% & 5\% & 10\% & &  \\
\hline
A & 2000 & 067 & $1.04\times 10^{-10}$  & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568  & y & 1669.3662 \\
\hline
B & 7000 & 304 & $3.94\times 10^{-13}$  & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & y & 168.168 \\
\hline
C & 5000 & -8.546 & $9.50\times 10^{-14}$  & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & y & 165.165 \\
\hline
D & 4000 & -2.659 & 0.081 & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & n & 1663.41 \\
\hline
E & 300 & -2.307 & 0.170  & -3.438 & -2.865 & -2.568 & n & 1.6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Update:
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Different types of datasets .} \label{tabadf}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Dataset}  &  Data type  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{CR} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{C time(µs)} \\
%\hline
\cline{1-1} \cline{4-11}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} &  & AA & LL & BB\_E & K\_RKL & AA & BBB & FF\_TRE & r\_E \\ 
\hline

A  & int8\_t   & 4.  & 0.   & .3 & 164   &  7  & 7   & 12245 & 301         \\  
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}


To achieve your stated formatting objective, it suffices to replace the second instance of \hline with \cline{1-2} \cline{5-7} and to replace the first instance of & & in the following row with \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} &.
I'd also like t encourage you to think about how your table might be made both easier to parse and to more visually appeal. (Right now, I hate to have to tell you, it doesn't score all that high on either scale. Sorry.) The second table below employs code that (hopefully) goes a long way toward achieving both of these additional goals. For instance, readers tend to welcome having numbers in columns aligned on their decimal markers.

\documentclass{article}
% Code for both tables:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}

% Code for second table:
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{5.5pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{Different types of datasets with data type Int32.} \label{tabadf}
\begin{tabular}{|c|r|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Dataset}  &  test   & $p$-value  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Critical} & ss? & Comp. \\
%\hline
\cline{1-2} \cline{5-7}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & & & 1\% & 5\% & 10\% & &  \\
\hline
A & 2000 & 067 & $1.04\times 10^{-10}$  & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568  & y & 1669.3662 \\
\hline
B & 7000 & 304 & $3.94\times 10^{-13}$  & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & y & 168.168 \\
\hline
C & 5000 & -8.546 & $9.50\times 10^{-14}$  & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & y & 165.165 \\
\hline
D & 4000 & -2.659 & 0.081 & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & n & 1663.41 \\
\hline
E & 300 & -2.307 & 0.170  & -3.438 & -2.865 & -2.568 & n & 1.6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\medskip

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercolumn spacing
\caption{Same contents, different layout} \label{tabadf2}

\smallskip
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l T{4.0} T{-1.4} T{1.2e-2,tight-spacing} *{3}{T{-1.3}} c T{4.4}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Dataset} & {test} & {$p$-value}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Critical} & ss? & {Comp.} \\
%\hline
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{5-7}
& & & & {1\%} & {5\%} & {10\%} & &  \\
\midrule
A & 2000 & {067}  & 1.04e-10 & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & y & 1669.3662\\ 
B & 7000 & {304}  & 3.94e-13 & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & y &  168.168 \\  
C & 5000 & -8.546 & 9.50e-14 & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & y &  165.165 \\ 
D & 4000 & -2.659 & {0.081}  & -3.437 & -2.864 & -2.568 & n & 1663.41 \\
E &  300 & -2.307 & {0.170}  & -3.438 & -2.865 & -2.568 & n &    1.6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Thank you, how can delete the line under the dataset to be one cell not two cell?

@stella - Omit \cline{1-2} (to get rid of the line entirely) or change it to \cline{1-1} (so that the line only extends over column 1).

Thank you. how can put the text in the middle of the cell ?

@stella - Which cell?

Dataset or test.

@stella - Do you mean horizontal or vertical centering?

vertical centering.

@stella - Thanks for providing this clarification. I can think of two methods. First, switch to the approach taken in the second table, i.e., start using \toprule, \midrule, \cmidrule, and \bottomrule instead of \hline. Second, if you must stick the (in my opinion) traditional-LaTeX method, aka \hline, I suggest you issue the instruction \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt} somewhere before \begin{tabular}. (If you want this setting to apply to the entire document, I'd issue the instruction in the preamble, after loading the array package.
